# Remote Desktop Connection - 2 Win7 Machines

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I can not seem solve this issue which prevents 2 x WIN7 machines on the same local network establishing RDC.

TeamViewer works fine. So not network issue.

Where should I look for error logs?
What should I try to debug the problem?

Comment: more info required.. what are the error messages, do you get to the login screen, do all users have permissions to rdp, is rdp service running?

Comment: In addition to @stijn's comments, Windows event logs may help.  Is firewall on?

Comment: The requested machine have RDP enabled?

Comment: The remove desktop client in Windows 7 is limited to a single connection.  You would need to be using Windows Server 2008 R2 in order to allow multiple users to connect to it at the sametime.

Comment: Is it Windows 7 Pro?  Home cannot be an RDP server.

Comment: @Ramhound actually there's a patch around which enables multiple connections and it works without any problems